# TransformToDevice doesn't return correct DPI factor on windows 8.1

Tags: wpf, transform, screen-resolution, dpi, dpi-aware

Hi I'm implementing DPI aware application where i want to calculate position of window based on current resolution.

I tested below code on windows 8.1 where OS doesn't ask for re-login if we change the DPI setting.
it apply the DPI immediately.

```
  var presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
  transform = presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;

  int width = transform.m11 * SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
  int height = transform.M22* SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

but if i change DPI using mspanel without logout and re-login, TransformToDevice() returns older value
instead of new one.
I thought that this transform matrix would change if the DPI settings changed.

Is there a method that I am supposed to call when the DPI settings change?

Comment: does it work after logout/re-login?

Comment: yes, it works after logout and re-login.

Comment: please help here. is there any other API which will return correct DPI value or or return current resolution? I tried other GetDeviceCaps(), GetSystemMatrics() and GetMonitorInfo() but all returns the value which was set before log-off, doesn't return currently set value.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure DPI settings of your environment but since you are talking about changing DPI "without logout and re-login", I assume Per-Monitor DPI feature of Windows 8.1 is enabled.

Under Per-Monitor DPI environment, the monitor DPI can be changed instantly without sign out and re-sign in, whereas the system DPI will not follow the change until sign out and re-sign in. Your code (it seems incomplete though) is to get the system DPI. Instead, you need to use [GetDpiForMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280510.aspx) by P/Invoke to get current monitor DPI.